# Get File from external URL with fs.readFile

Tags: node.js, express

I have links on a page that when clicked I want a external docx file to open. Unfortunately `fs.readFile` only reads local paths.

I tried

```
app.get('/getfile', function (req, res) {
   var externalURL = 'http://www.examplesite.com/example.docx';
   // var externalURL = req.query.external;
   fs.readFile(externalURL, function(err, data) {
      var fileData = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
      res.send(fileData);
   });
});
```

Comment: What error/output do you get when using the code you have posted

Comment: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

Comment: was that useful? mark as solve that question.

Comment: @TiagoFabre this only creates the file, but can you get the data inside original docx file and import it inside the new file?

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
const http = require("http");
const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.docx");

http.get("http://www.example.com/test.docx", response => {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.

Comment: I don't get it  (newbie here). Could you show this as a complete example in the context of the questions code?

Answer (score 0):

Try [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).
It follows regular client syntax for the fetch command ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)).

Comment: Please provide your solution using node-fetch

Answer (score 0):

you can use **get** from **http** package provided by nodejs library.

in my case i created a function that return a promise that is fulfilled when the file is completely fetched:

```
getFileFromURL(pathFile: string): Promise<Buffer> {

 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {//create a promise
  http.get(pathFile.replace('https', 'http'), function(res) {
    let bufferImage = Buffer.from(''); // create an empty buffer
    res.on('data', function(chunk) { // listen to 'data' event and concatenate each chunk when it is received
      bufferImage = Buffer.concat([bufferImage, chunk]);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      resolve(bufferImage); // fulfil promise 
    });
    res.on('error', function(err) {
      reject(err); // reject promise
    })
  })
})
}
```

and finally you can use the function like this:

```
async function() {
  const fileBuffer = await this.getFileFromURL('your external url');
// here you can you do what you want with your **filerBuffer**
// you can for example convert it to string like this: 
const fileString = fileBuffer.toString('utf-8');
// or may be send it in the response like this; 
yourResponse.end(fileBuffer); 
// ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### I'd recommend to use [request](https://npmjs.com/package/request) to do it.

I don't rly know you mean this...

TRY:

```js
const request = require('request');

request.get('http://examplesite.com/example.docx', function(err, res, body) {
  // Body is the example.docx data.

})
```