# Can't read content of online file in Node.js with XMLHttpRequest on the client

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my server in Node.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if(req.url == '/req_to_node') {
        res.writeHead(200);
        if(fs.existsSync(__dirname+'/file1.json')) {
            fs.readFile('http://example.com/file2.json', (err, contents) => {
                res.end(contents.toString());
            });
        }
    }

    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html', (err, contents) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(contents);
    });

}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

And this is code of my `index.html`

```
<script>
ajaxReq('req_to_node', function(result) {
    if(result != '') {
        console.log(result);
    }
});

function ajaxReq(slug,callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/'+slug);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callback(this.responseText);
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

As you see, with `XMLHttpRequest` on the client I'm trying to check if local `file1.json` exists and if yes, trying to read content of another `file2.json` which is online (on my own domain).

But in console I get the error

> GET http://localhost/req_to_node net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

While if I switch the file reading to the same local `file1.json` instead of the online `file2.json`, it works i.e.

```
...
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/file1.json', (err, contents) => {
...
```

ps. I'm interested in a solution without Express, if it's possible

Comment: the `fs` module is for interactive with the local file system and can't make network request, to get the conents of `http://example.com/file2.json` look at the `http` module example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284765/get-file-from-external-url-with-fs-readfile

Comment: Can I do it only with Express or without as well?

Comment: No, you can use it without as well, `http.get("http://example.com/file2.json", (contents) => { contents.pipe(res); });`

Comment: @dotconnor thank you! One more question: how to handle errors so that if the online `file2.json` is not accessed, the code would be getting local `file1.json` ?